# Sideload Javascript Addin (App) in Outlook for Ipad

Tags: ipad, outlook, office365, office-app

Does anyone managed to sideload an Javascript Addin in Outlook for Ipad?

I'm able to add it in Word and Excel, but I can't find any  "Add-ins" button in Outlook for Ipad so I can't view the add-in even if I add it for the same account in Outlook 356.

Thank you,
Raul

Answer (score 2):

The Mail add-in only support the OWA for Ipad. You can download this app from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/owa-for-ipad/id659524331?mt=8). And below are the detail requirements for the non-Windows smartphone and tablet. Specifically for OWA for Devices, and Outlook Web App running in a browser on smartphones and non-Windows tablet devices, the following software is required for testing and running Outlook add-ins.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - Link available here: [http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins)